# Take array input from a file

Tags: matlab, file-handling

I have a file in the first line is of the form:

```
6, [6; 2], 1000, 0.5, 0.01, [6 2], 0, 3.1416, [1 1 1]
```

Any of the cells can a vector/array, but only one dimensional

I tried taking input using `textscan`:

```
C = (fid, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f',1,'delimiter',',');
```

but this doesn't give me the right output.

How can I take this input such that I get all the arrays?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post a small runnable example (including a small sample file) and explain how the output differs from what you expect

Answer (score 0):

`textscan` with that format specifier is always going to fail because the `[`, `;`, `,` and `]` characters aren't going to be parsed properly.

You could instead split the string at the commas, and then use `str2num` to convert each piece into a number or array. This assumes that you never use `,` *within* an array.

```
value = cellfun(@str2num, strsplit(str, ','), 'uniform', 0)
```